# Using tryCatch() to fill a data frame in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, try-catch

I would like to check which data frames among 47340 are empty and save information about species and genes for those empty ones  into a list.

For that, I want to use a tryCatch() and when the df can not be read (so that means it's empty), catch the error and save it into a list.

Here is my code:

```
singletons <- duplicate_singletons %>% 
  filter(Branch == "Singletons") %>% 
  select(-c("dN/dS(w)", "Branch"))

species <- c("bovis", "becei", "panamensis", "inopinata", "tropicalis",
             "remanei", "latens", "tribulationis", "briggsae", "nigoni")

species <- species %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(. = "Species")


l <- list()
p <-  1

for(i in 1 : nrow(singletons)) {
  k <- list()
  m <- 1
  n <- 2
  for(j in 1: nrow(species)) {
    folder <- paste0(paste0("C:/Users/user/Documents/Travail/Synteny_project/R_files/Singletons/", singletons$gene_id[i]), paste0("/PSL/elegans_", species[j,], ".psl"))

    tryCatch({
      df <- read.table(file = folder, sep= "\t")
    }, error = function(e) {
      k[[m]] <<-  singletons$gene_id[i]
      k[[n]] <<- species[j,]
      m <<- m + 2 
      n <<- n + 2 
      })
  }

  k <- as.data.frame(k)
  l[[p]] <- k  
  p <- p + 1
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't fill the list k when an error occured.

Do someone knows why?

Comment: May I suggest a completely different approach? It seems to me that your error condition is the CSV file not being there or it having no lines. Why not use a file reading functions. For example, you can use file.exists() to check for the existing of a file and scan() or readlines() to check if the file is empty. That way you don't have to handle errors.

Comment: Oh I think you are right! I just want a way to check if my files are empty or not.
Thanks!!